# Python does not read the complete html file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, readfile

I an working in VS Code  on Windows 7. The  html file  that I am reading is in the project space. I have the following Python code in vs code to read the contents of  html - which has java script references, also html table- which I want to extract values from

I have the following code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("great.html","r")
contents = f.read()
print(contents)
f.close()
```

When I print(contents), i only see part of the html file in VS Code terminal. What could be problem.

I tried reading a simple xml file and it does have have behaviour

Thanks for your time

Comment: What does BeautifulSoup have to do with this?

Comment: Did you mean to write that the XML file does *not* have this behavior?

Comment: BeautifulSoup - is just there  because I want extract an html table . I removed  that line and getting the same outcome whether i read the .html  or XML file

Comment: if it is HTML file with JavaScript which generates content then you can't get this content using `open()` or even `BeautifulSoup` but you need web browser (or other tool) which can run JavaScript. Using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) you can control web browser to load HTML and run JavaScript, and later get HTML with all content.

Comment: I removed the beautiful soup line  and reading an XML file and still getting the same outcome, reading only partially

Comment: f = open("CCCD.XML","r")
contents = f.read()
print(contents)
f.close()

Comment: maybe terminal scrolled all text and you see only its end. You can try to scroll it up. But some terminals may have small buffer and they don't remeber older lines. You can also read it partially - `read(number_of_bytes_to_read)` - and use `input()` to read next part when you press ENTER.

Comment: Thanks I will try that,  appears to be buffer issue

Comment: that  certainly was the case -, I wrote  to another  file- after it was read and I could see everything in second file. Thanks so much